# Problems with Stripe Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm getting this error message whenever  I tried to start Rails server after installing Stripe gem.

```
$ rails s
/home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails323/gems/stripe-2.0.1/lib/stripe.rb:23:in `require': /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails323/gems/stripe-2.0.1/lib/stripe/errors.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL (SyntaxError)
...alize(message=nil, http_status: nil, http_body: nil, json_bo...
...                               ^
/home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails323/gems/stripe-2.0.1/lib/stripe/errors.rb:20: Can't assign to nil
...(message=nil, http_status: nil, http_body: nil, json_body: n...
...                               ^
/home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails323/gems/stripe-2.0.1/lib/stripe/errors.rb:20: Can't assign to nil
...tp_status: nil, http_body: nil, json_body: nil,
...                               ^
/home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails323/gems/stripe-2.0.1/lib/stripe/errors.rb:20: Can't assign to nil
/home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails323/gems/stripe-2.0.1/lib/stripe/errors.rb:39: class definition in method body
/home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails323/gems/stripe-2.0.1/lib/stripe/errors.rb:45: class definition in method body
/home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails323/gems/stripe-2.0.1/lib/stripe/errors.rb:52: class definition in method body
/home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails323/gems/stripe-2.0.1/lib/stripe/errors.rb:57: class definition in method body
/home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails323/gems/stripe-2.0.1/lib/stripe/errors.rb:60: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
...sage, param, code, http_status: nil, http_body: nil, json_bo...
```

I think that is a problem with my ruby version which is 1.9.3, as far as I know Stripe doesn't support ruby version 1.9, but I haven't find anything concrete about this. Do you guys know if is possible to have Stripe working with ruby 1.9?

Thank you!

Comment: It says it requires Ruby 2.0+ on the Stripe Github page. I don't think they are putting that in there just for fun. Sounds like time to upgrade your Ruby environment.

Comment: Their RubyGems page (https://rubygems.org/gems/stripe) says it requires >=1.9.3 though...

Comment: Someone should probably update this if it really does need 2+ https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/blob/master/stripe.gemspec#L8

Answer (score 1):

Your server should start up with Stripe version <= 1.58.0. It may be missing some features, but I was able to get a server running with that version and Ruby 1.9.3.